# GIT - sparse checkout not working as expected

Tags: git, github

I've a git repo checked out on a server.
The repo used to have all the relevant files on the root, but i had to make some changes and now i have two folders, `src` and `dist` and i want to track both.

The problem i've got is that on my server, if i pull, i now have to navigate inside dist folder in order to see something.

I tried to search a bit and i think that what i'd like to do is called sparse-checkout.

I followed this tutorial: http://jasonkarns.com/blog/subdirectory-checkouts-with-git-sparse-checkout/, in particular the part that talks about an existing project and i did what mentioned:

1. ssh into my server
2. cd into the project folder
3. git config core.sparsecheckout true
4. echo dist/ >> .git/info/sparse-checkout
5. git read-tree -mu HEAD

but nothing happend. I mean, i still need to navigate to myproject/dist to being able to see something.

I also tried to `cat sparse-checkout` file and `dist/` is present.
I tried `git pull origin master` as well, but with no luck.

Am i missing something here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You did everything as it should be.

---

## ***`sparse checkout`***

With sparse checkout you basically tell Git to exclude a certain set of files from the working tree. 
***Those files will still be part of the repository but they won't show up in your working directory.***

Internally, sparse checkout uses the ***`skip-worktree`*** flag to mark all the excluded files as always updated.

> ```
> # enable sparse checkout in an existing repository:
> git config core.sparseCheckout true
>
> # Create a .git/info/sparse-checkout file containing the
> # paths to include/exclude from your working directory. 
>
> # Update your working directory with 
> git read-tree -mu HEAD
> ```

[image]

---

## Another solution which might work for you as well:

***`Splitting a subfolder out into a new branch/repository`***

```
# use filter-branch to extract only the desired folder into a new branch
# once you done with your work you can always merge it back again.

git filter-branch --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter YOUR_FOLDER_NAME <branch>
# Filter the master branch to your directory and remove empty commits
```

Comment: This is handy, but how do you pull from the origin again without creating conflicts?  (e.g. how would I do a git pull and not pull everything down from origin when I only want the filtered)